# Using inappwebview package when i navigate to the web and open some product and when im swipping left to right i navigate to the welcome screen

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-inappwebview

I'm using inappwebview package in this as you can see in the video when I select a category and open a product I want to navigate back to that specific category but in my case, it navigates to the welcome layout can you please tell me how can I solve this?

If I use navigationandremoveuntil while navigating from home to this screen this problem is solved but I'm unable to navigate back to the welcome screen.

Comment: In one of my apps, I needed something like this, and I put a route to the previous page in AppBar. Btw there is no video , can you add some screenshots to make us understand it better?

Comment: hey bro. can you please share your email address so i can share you a video i dont know how can i post a video here @Miktad

Comment: Just add some screenshots, I don't know if we are allowed to share personal information here.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.